# ResponseBody cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, annotations, controller, response

I'm trying to write this method in my controller:

```
    @ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = {"/getTeams"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getMaxRequestSize(HttpServletResponse response) {
    String autoCompleteList = null;
    List<Team> teams = atService.getAllTeams();
    Iterator itr = teams.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        autoCompleteList += itr.next().toString() + "\n";
    }
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write(autoCompleteList);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For some reason I always get an error on the ResponseBody annotation (= cannot be resolved to a type). I googled for quite a while and didn't find a solution. I'm sure it's something silly. I can use all the other annotations without any problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a Maven project? You might be ending up with the old Spring 2.5.6 jars in your war file instead of Spring 3. Eclipse's POM editor's Dependency Hierarchy tab can help you figure out if that's the case.

Comment: I'm using an outdated version of Spring. I don't have the authority to upgrade to a new version, as I'm bound to 2.5.6... Any way to get around this?

Comment: Use Spring 3 anyway and tell them it's 2.5.6... it's meant to be backwards-compatible ;-) Seriously though, you're probably just not able to use that annotation. What do the reference docs for 2.5.6 (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/index.html) say?